# Google Maps API Webservices

Tags: json, web-services, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have been using the Google Maps Geocoding API Webservice for a few months now, and just recently it is giving me this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600%2BAmphitheatr…in%2BView%2C%2BCA&sensor=false. Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I am using the following code:

```
$.getJSON( "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json",
 { address : "1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA", sensor : "false" },
 function(data) {
  if (data.status == "OK") {
   alert("ok!");
  }
});
```

According to
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/
I should be able to use the webservice api as above.

I've also enabled the Google Maps v3 API and the Static Maps API in the Google API Console and set my domains to be allowed referrer domains but to no avail.

Anyone know why this suddenly stopped working and how I can fix it? I'd like to be able to keep using the webservices as opposed to the Javascript API if possible.

Comment: Is [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5973) relevant?

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I'm not sure I understand that issue @geocodezip. Considering the poster stated that it started occurring recently, it might be relevant, but it looks like he's using very different code to mine. Is there something I should add to my code to test whether it's the same issue?

Comment: your error `Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, his error `Origin http://xxx is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, seems the same to me.  Feel free to ignore it, or vote for that issue to see what happens (if anything).

Comment: I am having the same exact issue. I am not allowed to comment on your question because I do not have enough points, but wanted to let others know that this is a legitimate issue. I have code that hits google apis that has worked for 4 months and over the weekend it started giving me an allow-access-control-origin error.